# Populating MatTables with promises (asynchronous rows)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to display a collection of objects in a MatTable. I have a list with each object's URL, so I want to populate the rows asynchronously (I'm ok with having all the empty rows upfront, and then fill in the data as I load it)
So, this is my data source

```js
export class TableDataSource extends DataSource<Promise<any>> {

  private _items: Promise<any>[];

  constructor(private loader: LoaderService, private collection: ObjectMember) {
    super();
  }
  connect():  Observable<Promise<any>[]> {
    if (!this._items) {
      //aggregates each Promise<any> into an array.
      this._items = this.collection.value.map(x => this.mm.load(ObjectRepr, x.href));
    }
    return Observable.of(this._items);
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
```

and this is my table

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="CollectionSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" sort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name</mat-header-cell> 
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

This is showing the right number of rows, but they are not populated. The Promises are not getting resolved.

I've tried the following things but in both cases I got compile errors:

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element | async"> {{element.name}} </td>
```

and

```
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row| async"; columns: displayedColumns;">
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Observable.forkjoin() to handle the observable in for loop.

```
connect():  Observable<Promise<any>[]> {
    const observable = [];
    if (!this._items) {
      //aggregates each Promise<any> into an array.
      this.collection.value.forEach(x => {
          const obs = this.mm.load(ObjectRepr, x.href));
          observable.push(obs);
      });
    }
    return Observable.forkjoin(observable);
  }
```